# Python Pandas Filter but results are inversed

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I've built a filter where I expect the results to only show 'New'. However the result shows everything but new?

```
filt = (export['jiraStatus'] == 'New')
print(export.loc[~filt])
```

Thoughts?

TIA

Neil

Comment: Could you post dataset or just few rows to work on and expected output you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` negates/inverts the filter. Just use `.loc[filt]` instead of `.loc[~filt]` to get the un-negated result.

Comment: Dooh Sorry! The example i was using didnt make that clear! Thankyou!